# Document set options via CSOM

Tags: csom, document-set

I'm trying to disable the option "Add the name of the Document Set to each file name" for a document set I create via CSOM. I managed to set shared fields and welcome page fields, but I don't find this particular option. I think there should be a field or method of DocumentSetTemplate.DefaultDocuments, but there is nothing. Is it possible?

Thanks, Max